# Python : How can I send command lines to a (silent) running shell program

Tags: python, windows, shell, houdini

I work with python in Houdini, but bear with me as my question might not be only restricted to the Houdini environment.

Basically, Houdini comes with a "Hython" process that is supposed to be a Python shell
(see the end of this doc : https://www.sidefx.com/docs/houdini/hom/commandline.html)

At some point, Houdini can start multiple of these "hython.exe" without the shell interface, they are automatically managed in background using a server that dispatch instructions to them.
There is no explicit way to directly communicate with them using the API, but I want to be able to do exactly this.
Is there a way to send command lines to a running process (that is supposed to support them) ?

Very long shot part of my question : I'm trying to communicate with the hython processes as the server never tells them to flush their cache when a full set of computation has finished; leading to inflated memory consumption after a while and the need to stop/restart new hythons. It's already admitted by SideFx there is nothing in the API to ask for a cache flush (see here : https://www.sidefx.com/forum/topic/81712/)

I tried to embedd some naive "clear output" in the nodes processes I send to the hythons, to no avail.
"Unload" tag on nodes does nothing.
Node deletion doesn't understand context and will delete my project nodes before they are sent to a hython.

Comment: The [`subprocess` tag info page](/tags/subprocess/info) has a number of links to questions about interacting with a parallel process. Your question is rather vague so I'm not really sure which one to point you to as a possible duplicate, and also the horrors of using Windows might complicate things.

Comment: Thanks @tripleee, I'll seriously consider this idea, look a bit complex for me though; I should have mentioned I am not a seasoned python dev. Sorry for being vague, I think you understood well my problem, subprocess looks like a serious lead

Comment: The `pexpect` one might be conceptually simpler to work with than the others.